# Is there any way to get the Facebook widget to load from a local HTML file?

Tags: html, facebook

I'm doing some coding on a local file (in a tablet) and need the facebook widget to work, but it doesn't seem to show when done from a local file. Is there a way to get it to work?

The Code:

```
<html>

    <head></head>

    <body>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>
            (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        </script>
        <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook" data-tabs="timeline" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/facebook"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook">facebook</a></blockquote></div></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
```

That´s all you need to change. Without "http/https", the browser uses the protocol of the website. Since you don´t run a webserver on your tablet, there is no protocol - so you have to add it.

Comment: I did that and now i get a blank space. previously it showed the link, but it still doesn't show the Facebook widget

Comment: blank page means: check the browser console for errors ;)

Comment: try it on a real server, or at least with a local server and localhost - although, you can remove the https then.

Comment: Yes, it works on a server, just not on a local file.

Comment: I figured out the problem but not the cause: the iframe that gets created, for some reason has the style: `border: medium none; visibility: visible; width: 0px; height: 0px;`. If I change that (in "inspect element") to have a width and height, it shows! What causes this to happen? (The parent div has a width/height and I set the `data-width` and `data-height`)

Comment: it´s possible that the plugin just does not work without a server. try running a local webserver with localhost and it will definitely work.

Comment: It's odd. It does load locally and I can change it to be visible locally, but then after about 60 seconds, it makes it invisible again (and I can have a `setInterval` that checks and keeps making it visible). Why? It loads it and *then* sets it to a size of 0px on an interval.

Comment: it is actually pointless anyway, because sooner or later you will have to put it on a real server. that´s why it´s always a good idea to develop on a local server with localhost - similar to the real server.

Comment: meaning: i would not waste time on a workaround that´s most likely a bad idea anyway ;)